# Como exibir por ordem alfabetica - Cakephp

Tags: php, json, cakephp

Estou listando bairros, quando seleciono ao invés de pegar o valor da lista, o `json_encode` está retornando a posição dela. ex:

-BAIRRO I
-BAIRRO II

se eu seleciono o "BAIRRO II", ele vai me retornar: "1"

"0"-BAIRRO I 
"1"-BAIRRO II
...

Segue o codigo:

```php
    public function pegarBairros ($cidade = null) {
    $this->layout = 'json';
    $result = array();

    if (in_array($_REQUEST['cidade'], array_keys($this->cidade))) {
        $this->loadModel('Bairro');
        $bairros = $this->Bairro->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','bairro'), 'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->cidade[$_REQUEST['cidade']]),'group' => 'bairro'));
        sort($bairros);     
        foreach ($bairros as $bairro) 
            if (!empty($bairro)){
                $result[] = $bairro;
                $arr = $result;
                json_encode($arr);
            }
    } else $result[] = 'error';
    $this->set('data', $arr);
}
```

para eu mostrar, eu uso assim:

```php
echo $this->Form->input('bairro', array('label' => 'Bairro', 'empty' => 'Selecione o Bairro', 'options' => array() ));
```

O que está errado com o código?

E Como ordernar os bairros nesta linha no CakePHP?

```php
$bairros = $this->Bairro->find('list', 
    array('fields' => array('id','bairro'), 
          'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->cidade[$_REQUEST['cidade']])
    )
);
```

Comment: Furlan, na sua função original, tente rodar um `die(var_dump($bairros));` logo abaixo da sua função e poste o resultado.

Comment: Você tirou o contexto da pergunta toda, e as respostas ficaram sem sentido. Por favor volte e acresecente sua dúvida logo abaixo. Sua pergunta pode ser útil para outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Não seria porque você está atribuindo valor ao array sem declarar índice?

Neste caso, o interpretador agrega automaticamente o índice 0 ao início do array.

```
foreach ($bairros as $bairro) 
        if (!empty($bairro)){
            $result[] = $bairro;
            $arr = $result;
            json_encode($arr);
        }
} else $result[] = 'error';
```

Tente isto:

```
\\Seu código...
foreach ($bairros as $indice => $bairro) {
        if (!empty($bairro)){
            $result[$indice] = $bairro;
        }
 }
 //após iteração(foreach) de todo array, usar encode.
 json_encode($result);
} else {
$result = false;
```

Usando o padrão

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

Ele disponibiliza o índice do próprio array que você obteve no `find('list', $params)` através da variável `$key` .

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente o erro está ao montar o array de bairros.

O seu problema é a função sort. Ela reordena os índices do array, se colocar o banco ordenando seu problema é resolvido.

O CakePHP permite usar as seguintes posições como parâmetro do find.

```
array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
    'recursive' => 1, //int
    //array of field names
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'),
    //string or array defining order
    'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'),
    'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
    'limit' => n, //int
    'page' => n, //int
    'offset' => n, //int
    'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
)
```

para que o json fique assim:

```
{
    'bairros' : [
        'bairro1' : 1 // bairro => id,
        'bairro2' : 2,
        'bairro3' : 3
     ],
     success : true
}
```

O PHP ficaria assim

```
public function pegarBairros ($cidade = null) {
    $this->layout = 'json';
    $result = array();

    if (in_array($_REQUEST['cidade'], array_keys($this->cidade))) {
        $this->loadModel('Bairro');
        $bairros = $this->Bairro->find( 'list', array(
             'fields' => array( 'bairro','id' ),
             'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->cidade[$_REQUEST['cidade']]),
             'group' => 'bairro'),
             'order' => array('Bairro.bairro' => 'ASC')
        );
        $result['bairros'] = $bairros;
        $result['success'] = true;
    } else {
        $result['success'] = false;
    }
    $return = json_encode($result);
    $this->set('data', $return);
}
```

para que o json fique assim:

```
{
    'bairros' : [
        1 : 'bairro1' // id => bairro,
        2 : 'bairro2',
        3 : 'bairro3'
     ],
     success : true
}
```

O PHP ficaria assim

```
public function pegarBairros ($cidade = null) {
    $this->layout = 'json';
    $result = array();

    if (in_array($_REQUEST['cidade'], array_keys($this->cidade))) {
        $this->loadModel('Bairro');
        $bairros = $this->Bairro->find( 'list', array(
             'fields' => array( 'id','bairro' ),
             'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->cidade[$_REQUEST['cidade']]),
             'group' => 'bairro'),
             'order' => array('Bairro.bairro' => 'ASC')
        );    
        $result['bairros'] = $bairros;
        $result['success'] = true;
    } else {
        $result['success'] = false;
    }
    $return = json_encode($result);
    $this->set('data', $return);
}
```

Fonte [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Comment: eu coloquei no codigo, e os bairros não estao mais listados...oq sera?

Comment: Eu fiz uma correção no código agora você chegou a ver?

Comment: O seu problema era a funcão sort, ela reordena os índices do array, se colocar o banco ordenando seu problema é resolvido.

Comment: coloquei o seu codigo, mesmo assim não mostra os bairros, eu tirei o sort do meu codigo antigo la. mesmo assim nao vai...

Comment: coloca um `var_dump` na variável $bairros e e adiciona um `exit()` logo em seguida pra pegar o retorno, ou se tiver usando `xdebug` pegua o retorno e adiciona na pergunta para ter uma ideia melhor do que pode ser.

Comment: Adiciona tambem por favor, o código que ta usando para ler o json. Assim fica mais fácil ver o que pode ser

Comment: eu consegui resolver, agora so preciso colocar em ordem alfabetica...

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar o parâmetro `order`:

```
$bairros = $this->Bairro->find('list', array('order' => array('Bairro.bairro ASC'), 'fields' => array('id','bairro'), 'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->cidade[$_REQUEST['cidade']])));
```

O `ASC` não é necessário neste caso, como bem conhecemos no **SQL**, coloquei para que você possa ver que existe essa possibilidade, tanto `ASC` quanto `DESC`.

Comment: cara...nao rodo...ainda ta bagunçado